# Date converted from JSON incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sending 2 date ranges which represent the start and end of this current week. However the conversion of dates are not what I'm expecting on the server side. The start date is fine, but the end date is a day out which I don't quite understand why?

Console.log output

```
Date {Mon May 13 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)} 
Date {Sun May 19 2013 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)}
```

The JS that creates the above output

```
var startOfWeek = moment().day(1).hour(0).minute(0).second(0).toDate()
var endOfWeek = moment().day(7).hour(23).minute(59).second(59).toDate()
console.log(startOfWeek, endOfWeek)
```

JSON

```
{"Start":"2013-05-12T23:00:00.000Z","End":"2013-05-18T23:00:00.000Z"}
```

C#

```
Start: {13/05/2013 00:00:00}
End: {18/05/2013 23:59:59}
```

Controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllCampaignsByDate(DateRange _dateRange)
{
}
```

Model

```
public class DateRange
{
    private DateTime m_start;
    private DateTime m_end;

    public DateTime Start
    {
        get{ return m_start; }
        set { m_start = value.ToLocalTime(); }
    }

    public DateTime End
    {
        get { return m_end; }
        set { m_end = value.ToLocalTime().AddSeconds(-1); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your end date ends up being `{19/05/2013 23:59:59}`?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are passing the dates to the server as JS date objects and not strings?

Comment: The end date on the server side should be ending on Sunday 19th at 23:59:59, not Saturday 18th.

Comment: Yes they are date objects.

Comment: @user1883004 your JSON text says it's sending the date as the 18th though. If that is the case then the issue lies with *how* you are generating the JSON (hence my question).

Comment: I agree with James, the JSON example also shows 23:00:00 as the time, yet your C# shows 23:59:59.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with `moment.js` using [`ISO8601`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (the Z on the end of the string indicates UTC) and then going through `ToLocalTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a timezone problem. I am not sure which locale you are on but it appears as though you aren't taking into consideration DST. Make sure you are sending UTC dates from the client & not ones which are local to the client timezone.

Looking at the documentation for [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time

as it's effectively just a wrapper around the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object in JS, which by default:

> creates a JavaScript Date object for today's date and time according to local time

Therefore, you need to tell `moment.js` to convert the date you have created into UTC using [utc parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) e.g.

```
moment.utc(moment().day(1).hour(0).minute(0).second(0).toDate());
```